# starting with nodemcu/esp8266 dev board

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266, esplorer

I have a esp dev board that I've been trying to get to work, but have faild miserably. after spending a few days trying I was able to 'flash' a firmware and up load code(to connect to my wifi) via arduino IDE. the problems are when I open the serial monitor the serial monitor window is nowhere to be seen(it refuses to show up on my desktop, but if I place my mouse over arduino IDE on the task bar I can see a tiny version of the window with what seems like the esp is supposed to tell me). I verified the wifi program was working with advanced ip scanner. The other problem is that when I try to use esplorer I am told the following:

Communication with MCU..Got answer! Communication with MCU established.
AutoDetect firmware...
Can't autodetect firmware, because proper answer not received (may be unknown firmware). 
Please, reset module or continue.
à‚3þÿÖ
ü

I've tried reseting via hardware and software and also saving a init.lua to the esp ( which I am told: Waiting answer from ESP - Timeout reached. Command aborted.)

Is there an easy step by step tutorial or something where I can get this thing to work in such a way that it is possible to develop with it? I dont care what language I have to use as long as I dont have to spend more time on trying to get the hardware to work. For something that is Arduino-like hardware it is significantly harder to do the simplest thing, a pic mcu is easier.es

Comment: wait, do you have nodelua or ardunio firmware/bootloaders installed? you hint at both, which won't work.  did you add the esp8266 boards url to arduino? you can use any serial-port app to connect, not just the ide.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are doing serious IoT thing then, I guess its better to go by Espressif IDE. There's a Freetos version also available which makes programming experience better.
To get started step by step you can check lot of videos on youtube, that's my preferred way of getting started. I found these three helpful to get started : [here](https://pupilsys.com/tutorials/category/8266/)